# how to display inline:block on 2 divs and 1 has child divs

Tags: html, css

i have some html that looks like this:

```
<div id="main">hello</div>
<div id="second">
    <div id="one">hello</div>
    <div id="two">hello</div>
    <div id="three">hello</div>
    <div id="four">hello</div>
</div>
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get them to look like this:
[image]

I have tried display block but the separate divs messes it up for me. Any help would be much appreciated. thank you!

** --- EDIT ---**

I was asked to show my css, but it is basically just this. Also, please not that I CANNOT manipulate the HTML:

```
#main, #second, #one, #two, #three, #four {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your CSS

Comment: Is the `div#second` necessary? If not, you can apply `float: left` to all the divs, and set the container div to a certain width. Also, ID's cannot start with numbers.

Comment: @LaughDonor - Unfortunately, I cannot get rid of it.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña - I added my css. Please see the edit above

Comment: @JohnTobin - I was just doing it as an example... Changed

Comment: @JohnTobin you are wrong. `id` can be just a number, take a look at manual: [id @ HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: @scapegoat17: Is it necessary to have the 4 boxes inside another container 'second' with the layout you desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to get the clears in the right place.

```
#main,
#second > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float:left;
    margin: 4px;
}

#second > div:nth-of-type(2n) {
    clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTVz8/2/

Answer (score 1):

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdG8p/)

Basically I set your divs to `float:left`, and cleared them afterwards. Simplest solution. :)

Comment: You added a container around them. This allows them to float left within their container. I cannot do this unfortuantely.

Comment: The container is hypothetical.. it's whatever your divs are under. Even if it's <body>.

Comment: I understand that, but there are also other items inside my container. I feel like they will change the result

Comment: Then you should have put that inside your question. The point is as such, apply the `float:left` to each element you want to flow in that matter, and on the last one, apply the CSS inside the `:after` selector OR just apply `clear:left` on the first element after the stuff you want floated. The other HTML within that container div **makes a difference**.

Comment: I understand that which is why I did so.. Sorry, but it just slipped my mind at the time of the question

Comment: Then please update your question then and include the HTML for `main`'s container element too.

Answer (score -1):

In your case I would do the following, but this is without child divs:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TQ8YB/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">main</div>
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box clear">2</div>
<div class="box">3</div>
<div class="box clear">4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```